# Replacing values in dataset

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

First sorry for this newbie question, but I'm learning for myself so its a little more challenging.
I'm with a problem in replacing some negative values in one label of my dataset.
In a nutshel, I want to replace those negative values with a default value.
I tried doing the code below but didn't work.

```
dset['age'].replace(dset['age'] < 0 ,40)
```

Someone can help me?
I know that changing it on CSV file is easier, but I'm trying to get used do pandas library.

```
dset['age'].replace(dset['age'] < 0 ,40)
```

tried too:

```
dset['age'] = dset['age'].replace(dset['age'] < 0 ,40)
dset = pd.read_csv('credit-data.csv')
dset['age'].replace(dset['age'] < 0 ,40)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
dset.loc[dset['age'] < 0, 'age'] = 40
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace values conditionally as follow:

```
dset[dset < 0] = 0
```